# Why can't I strip whitespace with this Python comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to strip whitespace with a python comprehension:

```
instance_id_list = input("Enter instance IDs separated by commas: ")
instance_ids = instance_id_list.split(",")
[instance_id.strip(' ') for instance_id in instance_ids]
print(f"Instance IDs: {(instance_ids)}")
```

I'm entering a list of instance IDs with spaces left in the list like this:

```
i-0b956a2987c686dbd, i-0f6b1e1cdcabd2594, i-0307f123c3c9e6695, i-0425545775a09443d, i-00e48354b77e70484
```

But when I print out the result the spaces in the list are still there:

```
Instance IDs: ['i-0b956a2987c686dbd', ' i-0f6b1e1cdcabd2594', ' i-0307f123c3c9e6695', ' i-0425545775a09443d', ' i-00e48354b77e70484']
```

Why aren't the white spaces being stripped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to assign the results back to the variable:

```py
instance_ids = [instance_id.strip(' ') for instance_id in instance_ids]
```

Comment: Yep! That was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The line `[instance_id.strip(' ') for instance_id in instance_ids]` is not affecting anything. `strip()` *returns* a stripped string, it can't replace the string automatically with a stripped version, since strings are immutable. If you want a list of stripped `instance_id`s, you'd have to actually assign the result of the list comprehension to something:

```
stripped_instance_ids = [instance_id.strip(' ') for instance_id in instance_ids]
print(f"Instance IDs: {(stripped_instance_ids)}")
```

Comment: OK thanks, makes sense. I thought that the comprehension was affecting each element of the list. I now see that is wrong.